# Check if value of array is greater than. Than do other styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Iam currently working with jquery mobile and have an dynamic notification panel. Thereby I want to check the count of character in the text to base the styling on. So for example if `text of a notification is > 10` than set height to `Xpx`.

But what I first do is this:

```
for(var count = 0; count < info.data.length; count++){
    var shortmessage = info.data[count][3];
    var category = info.data[count][4];

    if(category === 'douane'){
        douaneHtml = douaneHtml + "<div class='notification-item'>" +
                                    "<div class='ui-grid-a notification-grid'>" +
                                    "<div class='ui-block-a'>" + 
                                        "<img class='notification-image' src=" + imgPath + ">"+ 
                                    "</div>" +
                                    "<div class='ui-block-b'>" + 
                                        "<span class='notification-text'>" + shortmessage +  "</span>" + 
                                    "</div>" + 
                                "</div>";

        $('.douane-notification-append').empty().prepend(douaneHtml); 
    }

}
```

So basically what I want to do is check:

```
if ( shortmessage.val().length() > 10 ){
    $('.notification-item').css('min-height', '100px');
 }
```

But when I do a `console.log(shortmessage.val());` inside the  `if(category === 'douane')` I'll get this in return:

```
shortmessage.val is not a function
```

Could someone help me out on this so basically what I want to do is count the characters in `shortmessage` and based on that do different styling.

This is the output of `console.log(info.data[count]);`

[image]

Comment: We've to see the `data` content.

Comment: From the looks of it `shortmessage` is not a jquery object and thus it is just as your message suggests that it does not have a `val` method

Comment: I made an edit to my post so you see what the output is. All strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shortmessage` is a `String`, you need to read the `length` property :

- I've cleaned up with string generation, use an array of strings and `join` them after. much nicer!
- Check if its too short and alter `style` variable
- Then use this in template

  ```
  for(var count = 0; count < info.data.length; count++){
      var shortmessage = info.data[count][3];
      var category = info.data[count][4];
      var style = '';

      // if long message, set the style
      if ( shortmessage.length > 10 ){
          style = 'min-height: 100px';
      }else if ( shortmessage.length > 20 ){
          style = 'min-height: 200px';
      }else if ( shortmessage.length > 30 ){
          style = 'min-height: 300px';
      }

      if(category === 'douane'){

          douaneHtml = [
              douaneHtml,
              "<div class='notification-item' style='" + style + "'>",
                  "<div class='ui-grid-a notification-grid'>",
                  "<div class='ui-block-a'>",
                      "<img class='notification-image' src=" + imgPath + ">",
                  "</div>",
                  "<div class='ui-block-b'>",
                      "<span class='notification-text'>" + shortmessage +  "</span>",
                  "</div>",
              "</div>"
          ].join('');

          $('.douane-notification-append').empty().prepend(douaneHtml); 
      }
  }
  ```

If you can, try the new ES2015 strings.
Cleans up code a lot.

```
   douaneHtml = `
                ${douaneHtml}
                <div class='notification-item' style='${style}'>
                    <div class='ui-grid-a notification-grid'>
                    <div class='ui-block-a'>
                        <img class='notification-image' src='${imgPath}'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='ui-block-b'>
                        <span class='notification-text'>${shortmessage}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
```

Comment: Hmm and how do I speak only to the notification item which has shortmessage.length is greater than 10?

Comment: Is it possible to set for different lengths for each an different height?

Comment: something like above?

Comment: No that doesn't work because 100px is for every notification-item

Comment: I have different categories like 'douane' and all have the same html markup. But now when I say if shortmessage > 45 for example it will change all the notification-items to the same height

Comment: So ofcourse it is greater than 10 and than it will change the height all to what i set in 10

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** `val()` method can't be called on string and since the `shortmessage` contains string message that will throw an error.

**Suggested solution :** just remove the extra `.val()` and it will works :

```
if ( shortmessage.length > 10 ){
    $('.notification-item').css('min-height', '100px');
}
```

**NOTE :** `length` is a property so you should remove the `()` from the `length`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: shortmessage.length is not a function` it throws me that error

Comment: `length` is a property, not a method

Comment: `.length` NOT `.length()`... length is a property of Strings, not a function....have a look at other answer.

Comment: @PhilPoore to be a StackOverflow player the next time you could just edit the post with typo instead of posting the same answer without this typo..

Comment: My bad, didn't realise i could edit others posts. I'll know for next time. Thanks Bro! :D

Comment: Hehehe yo guys and how can I change the height per length of shortmessage?>

Comment: What you mean exactly, describe more please.